# Cannot browse H2 in memory database from Java EE application

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, h2, h2db

I have a problem with connecting to H2 in memory DB from H2 console.
I am not using the Spring - just pure Java EE. I am specifying the H2 connection string in persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence-unit name="testPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source>jdbc:h2:mem:testdb</jta-data-source>
<properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
</properties>
```

Then when the application is started in one of my servlet I am starting the TCP and Web H2 servers:

```
Server.createWebServer("-web", "-webAllowOthers", "-webPort", "8082").start();
Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092").start();
```

Then I try to open localhost:8082 and enter the info which is required for connection:

- Driver class: org.h2.Driver
- JDBC URL: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb

First problem I see - it does not matter which user / password I put - connection is always successful. 
Another problem - when I press Connect I do not see any of my tables.
I know it is easy with Spring support. However, solutions which I found do not work for Java EE application.